# PowerShell and Winrm

Tags: powershell

Hi i am searching for all the power shell version and there corresponding winrm protocol version for example:
power shell 5.0 work with winrm 2.0

i tried googling it and did not find much information about it.
also searched the forum with no luck.

i need to know for which version of power shell uses which version of winrm.

PowerShell 1.0 ?
PowerShell 2.0 ?
PowerShell 3.0 ?
PowerShell 4.0 ?
PowerShell 5.0 winrm 2.0

If you know please also refer to me to a site where you found the answer.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can get the winRM stack version by using `$psversionTable`

```
PSVersion            5.0 
WSManStackVersion    3.0

PSVersion            4.0 
WSManStackVersion    3.0

PSVersion            3.0 
WSManStackVersion    3.0

PSVersion            2.0
WSManStackVersion    2.0

PSVersion            1.0
WSManStackVersion    ---
```

So 3,4 and 5 are using WinRM 3, PowerShell 2 uses WinRM 2 and PowerShell 1 does not support Windows Remote Management.